# Weird mesh deform when in object or pose mode

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, pose-mode

Okay, so I have this weird deforming on my mesh when I'm in either pose or object mode. I didn't have any issues with the bones and I've reset the rotation to have nothing change. I'm guessing it has something to do with the armature? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I've reset the pole rotation to zero like the other leg, which fixed the deformation. So it looks like this.. any tips would be great.
[image]

Comment: Maybe a problem of Pole Angle in your IK constraint? If not, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by locking the IK rotation on the x-axis. The tutorial I was watching when I made the armature had me do otherwise.
[image]